# Alamofire framework not found

Tags: git, xcode6, alamofire

I am trying to install alamofire into my project so I can upload images to my server, however I cannot seem to find the `alamofire.framework` file. I have downloaded the git twice, done the installation instructions on `https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire` but when it comes to `step 6`, how and where do I get the `alamofire.framework` file?

I am new to this, so sorry if it is a stupid question.

Answer (score 45):

You have to open yourprojectname.xcworkspace

You might get this error if you are opening your .xcworkproj instead of workspace

Answer (score 28):

1. Close your Xcode project
2. Re-Open your project with the Xcode workspace file and not with the .xcodeproj

This work fine for me !

Comment: 2 days hustling with this error until I landed on your answer! Long live stackoverflow

Answer (score 8):

You just need to change `Framework Search Paths` to `$(inherited)`.

P.S: **Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Framework Search Paths**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I solve my problem with this way (Only if your case are you have imported Alamofire in project but still not found)

1. Close all your project and your XCode
2. Re-Open your XCode Apps then select bottom text
   [image]
3. Choose your project, do not select file inside. Just click open on folder project name
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

I removed the `Alamofire`  from pod file but I got the error again finally I figured out `Alamofire` exist in `Target -> Build setting -> Other Linker Flags` and remove from there and build successfully finally.

Comment: ain't seeing anything there

Answer (score 1):

Use **Cocoapods** to integrate **Alamofire** in your project:

To add Alamofire into your project please do the following steps:

add the below lines into your **pod file**.

```
  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not stupid!

- Click the little (easily missed) + button in the bar under General, Build Phases, etc. and in the dropdown click **New Copy Files Phase**
- Double click the title and rename it "Copy Frameworks" (optional)
- Change destination to *Frameworks*
- Add Alamofire.framework

Once it's linked it doesn't necessarily exist on your device, this ensures it will.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, and '$(inherited)' was missing in Target -> Build Settings ->Framework Search paths. Giving this fixed my issue.